# Jsoup, table and combinaison of pseudo selector

Tags: java, html-table, jsoup

I'm currently using a network software(IxChariot). This soft exports the output into the html format. And I would like to create a soft which transform the html code from Ixchariot to an other html code(I would like to add some tips and remove some useless information).

I need to remove some table but the only difference between the table is the title.

Example of html code :

```
<TABLE CELLPADDING=3 BORDER=1 style="page-break-inside : avoid">
<H2>Run Options</H2><BR>
```

Other example :

```
<TABLE CELLPADDING=3 BORDER=1 style="page-break-inside : avoid">
<H2>Test Setup (Console to Endpoint 1)</H2><BR>
```

To perform that I'm trying to use pseudo selector from jsoup like that :

```
Elements table = doc.select("table:has(h2:contains(Run Options)").remove();
```

I already tried like that too :

```
Elements table = doc.select("table");
table:has(h2:contains(title));
```

But It's not working,(currently, all the code is remove). 
Could you help me with the pseudo selector ? Or if you have a better idea..

ps: I'm not an expert, I just have some basic knowledge in programming.

Comment: if what you posted is the final html, it is not parsed correctly by jsoup

Comment: Final html ? What do you mean ? The html code after the transformation by jsoup ? The html from Ixchariot ?

Comment: the html data that jsoup parses to `doc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe problem is that `<H2>` is not element expected to be inside `<TABLE>` so it is removed by JSoup. In that case try simple XML parser instead of default HTML parser. You can do it with

```
Jsoup.connect(yourUrl).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get()
```

Comment: I will try but to be honest, I don't have any knowledge in XML.
As I said i'm not an expert, I'm currently an network administrator.

Comment: HTML is kind of XML. Try to use this parser same way you would do with default HTML parser and you should be fine.

Comment: As i use a local file it's more like 
File input = new File("test.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, Parser.xmlParser());
no ?

Comment: You can try with `Jsoup.parse(new FileInputStream("test.html"), "utf-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());`. Just make sure to provide correct encoding of html file.

Comment: I found a similar way but yours is smarter. And it's working well so thanks a lot ;)